# Determine mailbox access protocol using C#

Tags: email, c#-4.0, imap, pop3

I racked my brain about how can i determine what protocol is used by a mailbox.
I'm creating a simple C# application that get an email adress and read all the mails, first of all i have to know how to access to this mailbox (which protocol to use) - i'm looking for a way to check what it the appropriate protocol (and please don't suggest me to try accessing all of them).

BTW, I don't have any limit which framework to use.

hanks in advance!!!
I'll appriciate a quick (and good :)) respone!

Comment: Do you mean IMAP vs POP, unencrypted vs TLS, or what?

Comment: just to determine the protocol (pop, imap or http - the protocoles used for read mails) - tls could be better but it's out of my scope for now.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell just from an address what access methods might work.  There are the 2 core protocols (POP3 and IMAP) and their SSL variants.  Additionally, there's all the other info you need related to the address (mail server running POP3/IMAP/etc.)

The general use case here is handled by getting the appropriate data (including protocol) from the user.

Comment: I can't get this data from the user.
Is there any way to know the MAIL SERVER protocol?
I know that web2mail do it so it's possible. 
(maybe there is no direct way to get this data except of trying retrieve a mail?)

Comment: I'd guess that web2mail does a few things - 1, guesses at a variety of names of the mail server (based on the domain), then 2, tries a variety of ports associated with common protocols until it finds one that works.